# Makefile target-specific variable and multiple calls to base target "nothing to be done"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

What I would like to do with GNU Make is to have a single base target that can be called with slight variations depending on the actual target called. To accomplish this, I tried using target-specific variables as shown below (minimal example):

`Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all _base_target target1 target2

all: target1 target2

target1: MYVAR="first"
target1: _base_target

target2: MYVAR="second"
target2: _base_target

_base_target:
        echo "MYVAR is $(MYVAR)"
```

So, this works perfectly fine for working with a single target:

```
$ make target1
echo "MYVAR is "first""
MYVAR is first
$ make target2
echo "MYVAR is "second""
MYVAR is second
```

However, when I want both targets to be run (via `all` or separately):

```
$ make -n all
echo "MYVAR is "first""

$ make -n target1 target2
echo "MYVAR is "first""
make: Nothing to be done for `target2'.
```

How can I adjust my Makefile to have it run the base target for each? I.e. I would like `make all` to behave as if I did `make target1; make target2`.

The `.PHONY` option appears insufficient, apparently. Since I'm lacking the proficiency with GNU Make in terms of vocabulary it appears hard to find useful results for this using Google.

#### Double-colon attempt

In response to the answer about the use of Double-colons [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40657060/1254292).

```
[...]
all:: target1
all:: target2
[...]
```

yields the same result.

Replacing all single-colons with double-colons yields also the same result.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I adjust my Makefile to have it run the base target for each?

You cannot have one base target when using the regular dependency. The reason is that `make` executes the recipe to update the target once, whereas you would like to update it multiple times with the different value of `MYVAR`.

Comment: Documentation quote sounds promising, but it's not working even if would replace all my single-colons to double colons in the example Makefile. Could you elaborate a bit more on what I should change? The documentation is lacking examples.

Comment: @gertvdijk If the base target produces a file and the contents of it are influenced by `MYVAR` than you need two different targets.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following your statement. I already have individual targets for the variations and the main point of my question is to use a single base target as 'template'.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thinking more about it, double-colon rules won't help you, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this within a single instance of GNU make.  Make will only ever attempt to build a single target one time, at most, per invocation.

What you can do is use recursion:

```
.PHONY: all _base_target target1 target2

all: target1 target2

target1: ; $(MAKE) _base_target 'MYVAR="first"'

target2: ; $(MAKE) _base_target 'MYVAR="second"'

_base_target:
        echo "MYVAR is $(MYVAR)"
```